# Save 3D array as a 3D tif image

Tags: python, image-processing, tiff, scikit-image

I am trying to save a 3D array to a tif image. Below is my code. 
I tried to do it both ways and they both did work. They gave me a "tif" file that cannot be opened by matlab, ImageJ or just good old preview on mac.

```
test = maskImage[:,:,:]
skimage.external.tifffile.imsave('output.tif',test)#first way

with tif.TiffWriter('temp.tif', bigtiff=True) as tif:#second way
 for i in range(test.shape[0]):
     tif.save(test[i], compress=6)
```

Can someone please help me? I really appreciate it.

Comment: What is the shape and dtype of `test`?

Comment: HI, the shape is (60,1024,1024) and the type is nd.array.

Comment: What is `test.dtype`? Also, what are the error messages for `cannot be opened by matlab, ImageJ`

Comment: The dtype is float64. The ImageJ error message is "File is not in a support format, a reader plugin is not available. "  I can open these in Matlab but they are just black. I know these aren't actually empty because when I set Z axis to a certain number and use plt.show in python, I can see the 2D image with content.

Comment: Yes, the ImageJ TIFF reader does not support float64. Try import via BioFormats or save the data as float32 `imsave('output.tif',test.astype('float32'))`. Re Matlab, it's probably just a matter of setting the right display range min and max.